# how to install the Pentaho Data Service JDBC Driver to my java backend application?

Tags: java, pentaho

I am trying to connect to Pentaho data service from my Java backend API. I followed this [link](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0L0/0Y0/090/040#Install%20Driver) to download necessary JDBC driver files and got a bunch of following jar files. How do I install these jar files to my java web api? Do I just need to import all of them like a regular jar files?

[image]

Comment: What is your database ? MySQL? PostgesSQL ? MS-SQL? Oracle?

Comment: Hi my database is using Postgresql, so my colleague is doing data transformation with Pentaho. My backend is supposed to fetch data from Pentaho data service for transformed data.

Answer (score 2):

Download the JDBC [there](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html).

Copy the jar in the folder [your-biserver-install-folder]/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lib.

Restart Pentaho.